# Select parent rows and include cost of children

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, maximo, oracle19c

I have a WORKORDER table that has parent and child WOs in it:

```
with workorder as (
select 'WO37342' as wonum,      null as parent, 297.36 as actlabcost, 200 as actmatcost, 0 as actservcost, 0 as acttoolcost from dual
union all
select 'WO37427' as wonum, 'WO37342' as parent,  99.12 as actlabcost,   0 as actmatcost, 0 as actservcost, 0 as acttoolcost from dual
union all
select 'WO37429' as wonum, 'WO37342' as parent,  99.12 as actlabcost, 100 as actmatcost, 0 as actservcost, 0 as acttoolcost from dual
)
select
    * 
from
    workorder

 WONUM   PARENT  ACTLABCOST ACTMATCOST ACTSERVCOST ACTTOOLCOST
 ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
 WO37342             297.36        200           0           0
 WO37427 WO37342      99.12          0           0           0
 WO37429 WO37342      99.12        100           0           0
```

---

I want to select the parent rows and include the cost of the children in the parents:

```
 WONUM    ACTLABCOST ACTMATCOST ACTSERVCOST ACTTOOLCOST
 ------- ----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
 WO37342       495.6        300           0           0
```

---

Is there a concise way of doing this in Oracle 19c?

*(My goal is for the SQL to be as simple/readable as possible.)*

Comment: Just children or all descendents?

Comment: @MTO There is only a child level. There aren't any lower-level descendants (no grandchildren, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one-level parent/children relationship, as shown in your sample data, I would recommend:

```
select  
    coalesce(parent, wonum) wonum
    sum(actlabcost)  actlabcost, 
    sum(actmatcost)  actmatcost,
    sum(actservcost) actservcost,
    sum(acttoolcost) acttoolcost
from workorder wo
group by coalesce(parent, wonum)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a hierarchy with multiple levels you can use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT( ... )` and then `GROUP BY` that:

```sql
SELECT root_wonum AS wonum,
       SUM( actlabcost ) AS total_actlabcost,
       SUM( actmatcost ) AS total_actmatcost,
       SUM( actservcost ) AS total_actservcost,
       SUM( acttoolcost ) AS total_acttoolcost
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( wonum ) AS root_wonum,
         actlabcost,
         actmatcost,
         actservcost,
         acttoolcost
  FROM   workorder
  START WITH parent IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR wonum = parent
)
GROUP BY root_wonum;
```

Which, for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE workorder ( wonum, parent, actlabcost, actmatcost, actservcost, acttoolcost ) as
select 'WO37342',      null, 297.36, 200, 0, 0 from dual union all
select 'WO37427', 'WO37342',  99.12,   0, 0, 0 from dual union all
select 'WO37429', 'WO37342',  99.12, 100, 0, 0 from dual;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> WONUM   | TOTAL_ACTLABCOST | TOTAL_ACTMATCOST | TOTAL_ACTSERVCOST | TOTAL_ACTTOOLCOST
> :------ | ---------------: | ---------------: | ----------------: | ----------------:
> WO37342 |            495.6 |              300 |                 0 |                 0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a9ade2d408118f58a6a50b8c3c16f9b)*